# Qual a diferença entre printf() e print()?

Tags: java, console

Eu estava fazendo alguns algoritmos simples em Java e na maioria das vezes se usa `System.out.println()` ou `System.out.print()`, porém para fazer a definição do número de casas decimais estou usando `System.out.printf()`. Sei que há diferença entre as duas primeiras, tanto em funcionamento como em implementação. Mas qual a diferença entre elas e a última?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

O mais comum em Java é usar `System.out.print()` (ou com o `ln` se quiser que pule linha, mas isto você já sabe) mas se você precisa de certas formatações o uso do [`System.out.printf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf-java.util.Locale-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) pode ser mais adequado. Este método funciona de forma muito semelhante ao [`printf()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) do C utilizando a classe [`Formatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html).

Exemplo:

```
System.out.print("x: " + x + " y: " + y);
System.out.printf("x: %d y: %d", x, y);
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/o0eWEG). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/fogueyjv-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/IO/Print.java).

Além de ser mais prático em várias situações também pode ser bastante útil onde tem localização de textos ou outras formas de parametrização destes textos.

Comment: Muito esclarecedora a classe Formatter, grato!